# Can a 110v 3-wire thermostat be hooked up to a 110v 2-wire condo setup?

Tags: wiring, hvac

My condo that was built in 1968 has an old thermostat(rheostat type) which supplies 2 thick gauge black wires of which one is live and the other isn't. This regulator is hooked up to a blower unit(fan) which is connected to a central ventilation system that brings hot or cold air to it. In attempting to upgrade to a programmable thermostat type, how would a single pole King Model ESP120-R that runs on 110v which has a set of red, black and white wires be connected to my unit's 2-wire setup?

Comment: How long are the wires between the fan and the thermostat?

Comment: All I can see are the two black wires mentioned coming out of the wall which go to the old thermostat I'm trying to replace. These are about 1.5ft long each

Answer (score 1):

The King Model ESP120-R is not compatible with your wiring.  The third wire is the neutral, which this electronic thermostat requires to be operable.  Your original thermostat functions as a temperature controlled switch, connecting or disconnecting the heat without any need for externally supplied power.  Either you need a new replacement thermostat that also uses no separately supplied power, or you need to have your wiring altered.

Comment: If the old thermostat is not powered, why is there a hot wire coming to the old thermostat? I was guessing that the thermostat serves to regulate 110v supply that goes to the blower so when the temperature is reached on the thermostat, it cuts off the power to the blower, stopping it from working. Fyi thermostat has a switch for heat and cool. It seems to just regulate the temp in reverse if switched to cool in the winter or heat in the summer.

Comment: How would the wiring need to be altered? Was thinking that if the 110v line could be stepped down to 12v or 24v, there are alot more thermostat model options. Or is that too simplistic... what's your take on that?

Comment: Too simplistic.  It is not the hot leg that is missing, it is the neutral.  The two wires you have are:  (1) Hot supply leg, (2) Switched leg to blower.  With no neutral at the thermostat location you have no ordinary way to supply power to your control device separately from the blower.  Options for line voltage thermostats are limited, but converting to low voltage would again involve significant wiring changes.  Anything is possible with sufficient money and expertise.  Unfortunately, there is not a trivially easy way for you to change your thermostat type in this situation.

Comment: What about this thermostat that has only 2 wires and is single pole? http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000AUKVU4?app=1BA&ascsubtag=1ba_0_spk_000-os-device-browser-localeTest-testApp-custom%3AA%7Ccustom%3AB&partner=amazon&platform=CR&programCode=org&ref_=bit_bit_org_1ba-cr_def_us_title&tag=bit-org-1ba-cr-us-20&tagbase=abba-chrome

Comment: Can a neutral be brought to the new thermostat location?

Comment: If you look at the spec sheet for the TH106/U, you will notice that it says "Minimum Load 2 A (resistive only)."  This means the unit cannot be used to control a blower or even a remote relay.  It is only able to control a resistive electric heater.  A neutral can be brought to the thermostat location, absolutely yes.  This might be easy or difficult for an electrician, depending on how accessible the wiring in your condo is.

Answer (score 0):

A two wire unit requires one hot wire, and one wire that will become hot. Whereas a three wire unit also needs a "neutral" wire, so that it can draw power itself.

The two wire unit simply connects and disconnects the two wires. The three wire unit does that too, but also uses a "neutral" wire so it can draw power for itself.

If you want to use a three wire unit, you'll have to expose a "neutral" wire.